# FormGroup form errors is null Angular Reactive Forms

Tags: angular

When using Reactive Forms, a formGroup containing FormControls which are invalid(invalid form) is shown as invalid which is normal, but it does not contain any errors.

I should be able to get all the errors from the form in the formGroup.errors but it is null

However, The form state is invalid and under every invalid formControl it gives me the validation error
What am I missing ?

check for errors:

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from "@angular/forms";
import { DB1 } from 'src/app/interfaces/IDB';
import { DBS } from 'src/app/consts';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-dashboard',
  templateUrl: './new-dashboard.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-dashboard.component.scss']
})
export class NewDashboardComponent implements OnInit {
  dbs: string[] = ["DB1", "DB2"]
  selectAxisOptions:string[]  = []
  newDashboardForm = new FormGroup({
    name: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    db: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
    axis: new FormControl({ value: null, disabled: true }, [Validators.required])
  })
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
  resetForm() {
    this.newDashboardForm.reset()
  }
  onSelectionChanged(evt) {
    let value = evt.target.value;
    this.axis.enable();
    switch (value) {
      case 'DB1':
        {
          this.selectAxisOptions = [...DBS.get("DB1").values()]
          break;
        }
      case 'DB2':
        {
          this.selectAxisOptions = [...DBS.get("DB2").values()]
          break;
        }

    }
  }
  onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.newDashboardForm);


  }
  get name() {
    return this.newDashboardForm.get('name')
  }
  get db() {
    return this.newDashboardForm.get('db')
  }
  get axis() {
    return this.newDashboardForm.get('axis')
  }
}
```

html:

```html
<div class="modal-body">
    <form [formGroup]="newDashboardForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
        <input formControlName="name" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Dashboard Name">
        <select formControlName="db" (change)="onSelectionChanged($event)" class="custom-select">
            <option disabled="true" [selected]="true">select DB</option>
            <option *ngFor="let db of dbs">{{db}}</option>
        </select>
        <select formControlName="axis" class="custom-select">
            <option disabled="true" [selected]="true">select column</option>
            <option *ngFor="let column of selectAxisOptions">{{column}}</option>
        </select>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Dashboard</button>
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Is the first list missing `this` keyword in the first line of the code (so instead of `newDashboardForm` shouldn't it be `this.newDashboardForm`)?

Comment: no, it is in the initialization of the class

Comment: `invalid` is also true when child elements are validated and invalid, but for every group, even the form, the `errors` property only contains errors for that control itself. In other words: You only see errors in the form control if you added a validation to the form itself. Currently you only added validation errors to every child control. So you have to read the errors from every control.

Comment: got you, how do I add the functionality of seeing the invalid fields in the errors of the formGroup ?

Comment: Something like: `form.controls.get('axis').errors`

Comment: Or for all fields: `form.controls.forEach(c => c.errors)`

Comment: I have the same problem as you, did you solve it ? Please share it with me, thank you!

Answer (score 10):

You have validators on single form control, not on the whole form group. Then you have errors only on the invalid field. You can loop every control and get every single form control error like that

```
  onSubmit() {
    // Get all Form Controls keys and loop them
    Object.keys(this.newDashboardForm.controls).forEach(key => {
      // Get errors of every form control
      console.log(this.newDashboardForm.get(key).errors);
    });
  }
```

You can check the stackblitz here [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-shev1d?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 1):

Change initial value from "" (empty string) to null.

Answer (score 1):

Do your validation initializations inside the `ngOnInit()` method.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced similar issue lately. The FormGroup track the states wether the overall form is valid or not, but don't show specific errors.

The errors are specific for each controller, and to see each error you must go through each controllers.

A good approach i saw is to prepare `Property` for each controller

```
get name() { return this.newDashboardForm.get('name') }
get db() { return this.newDashboardForm.get('db') }
...
```

This will enable you to use the controller as normal variable inside the component and also the template.

Now to see each the error message in the controller use.

```
this.name?.errors
```

To view the errors on the template you can use it as

```
{{ name?.errors | json}}
```